# How to force Zingchart to refresh

Tags: zingchart

We use socket library to download data from our service. I am doing the following the send this data to zingchart (after massaging of data):

```
myChart.series[0].values.push([xVal, yVal]); // index 0 is hard coded for demo
```

The charts don't refresh though. We would like them to feel like real-time.

Answer (score 7):

ZingChart doesn't have two-way data-binding so modifications to the data object after render won't take affect.

However, ZingChart does have a pretty killer API. If you're trying to append values to the series, try the [appendseriesvalues](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/api-methods/#zingchart__exec__api__appendseriesvalues) method. It should look something like this...

```
zingchart.exec("your_chart_id", "appendseriesvalues", {
    values: [xVal,yVal]
});
```

If you're trying to simulate real-time, you could even toss it in a [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function and have it request data regularly.

I work on the ZingChart team. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Can you share an example where the X-Axis is date. The one I tried isn't quire working. Here is what I got so far: 
var myChart = { "utc": false,  "type": "line", "title": {"text": "Test"},
                "series": [{"values": []}],
                "scale-x": {"values": [],  "zooming":true, "transform":"type":"date"}
                }, "scale-y":{ }
            };

zingchart.render({ id: "myChartDiv", data: myChart });

Following your suggestion, I added the following and it doesn't do anything. 

 zingchart.exec("myChartDiv", "appendseriesvalues", { values: [(new Date()).getTime(), 20] });

Comment: @user4415719 Just stick the `values` inside another array like so: `values: [ [(new Date()).getTime(), 20] ]`.